# Send Unauthenticated Request to a Different Action Route

Tags: scala, filter, playframework, interceptor, playframework-2.3

I am implementing a global filter across all requests to identify that the user who is making the request is authenticated, and if not send them to the login screen.

My Global object extending the WithFilters class which is using the Authentication Filter:

```
object Global extends WithFilters(AuthenticationFilter()) { }
```

My Authentication Filter:

```
class AuthenticationFilter  extends Filter {
  def apply(next: (RequestHeader) => Future[Result])(request: RequestHeader): Future[Result] = {
    println("this is the request that will be filtered: " + request)
    if (!authenticated) 
      // How do i send the request to the login Action?
    else 
      next(request)
  }
}

object AuthenticationFilter {
  def apply(actionNames: String*) = new AuthenticationFilter()
}
```

My question is how do I go about sending an unauthenticated user to the login Action/route?

Comment: I think this would be so much easier if you were using Spring. Just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Create a trait for the secured routes.  In that trait when unauthenticated requests come in redirect them:

```
trait Secured {

/**    
 * Retrieve the connected user name from the request header.  
 */   
private def username(request: RequestHeader) = request.session.get("username")

/**    
 * Redirect to login if the user in not authorized.    
 */
private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)


/**    
 * Action for authenticated users.    
 */   
def IsAuthenticated(f: => String => Request[AnyContent] => Result) = Security.Authenticated(username, onUnauthorized) { user =>
  Action(request => f(user)(request))   
}


}
```

Now define any controllers you want to be secured to extend that trait and unauthenticated requests will be sent away:

```
object Index extends Controller with Secured
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to create authentication for specific controllers or Actions, i want authentication to be checked for every request.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do it on the global object because at least one request (the login page) will have to not be authenticated

Comment: Let's assume this works. How would i forward the request to the Login Action

Comment: I think you would just put this line in your global object: `private def onUnauthorized(request: RequestHeader) = Results.Redirect(routes.Application.login)`